# How to find registry folder by match in it`s value

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, batch-processing, registrykey

I am writing a batch file to search the registry.
I need to find the folder inside `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products` which ProductName key equals to "MyProduct".
I need to find this folder and delete it.

This folder I want to delete will look like this: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\1A0614C849C672CF0A680DCFA3921735`

Comment: Open a cmd console and type the help Reg Query /? And Reg Delete /?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, change `MyProduct` to your actual `ProductName` string leaving the closing doublequote untouched, on line `4`:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "App=MyProduct"
Set "Key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products"

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Query "%Key%" /S /F
 "%App%" /D /E 2^>NUL ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe" /I /R /X
 "%Key:\=\\%\\[^^^\\]*"^"'
) Do Echo="%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Delete "%%G" /F ^>NUL
Pause
```

The above will only print the deletion line that you intend to run. Once you are satisfied it is correct, to actually delete it, change the code to the following, (remembering to change your `ProductName` string again). *Please note, that as you're deleting a key from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, you will most likely need to run this script elevated, or as a user having sufficient permissions for doing so.*:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Set "App=MyProduct"
Set "Key=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products"

For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('^""%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Query "%Key%" /S /F
 "%App%" /D /E 2^>NUL ^| "%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe" /I /R /X
 "%Key:\=\\%\\[^^^\\]*"^"'
) Do "%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe" Delete "%%G" /F >NUL
```